# Google Drive and hosting a custom receiver for chromecast

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm using my android app's website (http access) to host the receiver code during my development of my app w/ Chromecast. I have it working fine and ready to get the custom receiver code (html, css, js files/directories) on my Google drive. The directory on my Google drive holding all those files/directories is shared publicly.

The problem comes in when I setup my Chromecast (in Google Cast SDK Developer Console) to point to the new location of the index.html file, I right mouse click (in the Windows 7) the index.html and choose Google Drive/Share. The "link to share" value isn't the correct value to put into the Google Cast Dev Console. When I go to cast my app I get the .html content shown on the casted screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,Jim

Comment: Look at this support page on host to host pages on drive and how to get the URL: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

Comment: I saw that URL and didn't see the Open link in lower right corner. Where i actually found the URL for hosting was by "visit google drive on web" menu item for the Google Drive icon in the Windows 7 task tray . When the browser opened it had my directory. Clicking the checkbox allowed the right side of the page to have 2 tabs: Details and Activity. Clicking Details tab had the "HOSTING" url. But thank you for your original quick reply Leon. You're a huge benefit to the ChromeCast.